# Urlib2 is downlloading Corrupted pictures

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to download a picture with urllib.

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://sabacorpusa.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/72r-n3f2wmyhdt4llirtxxedqby6ezqukrlfqk0jp0jxjq-n3f33lxe2ko5pena8fvrs5fcmikxfqmykfapmdtl06.jpg", "local-filename.jpg")
```

It downloads but the image is corrupted

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: A picture gets downloaded but check i click on the picture on the local computer Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x68)

Comment: `0x3c 0x68` is `<h`: my guess: You are getting an HTML error page instead of the image

Comment: okay ill check that in the shell thankyou

Comment: Thank You that worked for me

Comment: Yes that was the problem thankyou